# WPF C# Control with variable number of columns to add value to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I need a control with many columns and one row. Content of each column would be added to database. Number of columns can be varied. And depending on that I would insert data to sql table. 
Which is the best?

How can I insert all data from this control to sql? Maybe cycle? I do not wanna insert every column manually. But I need access to every column of it.

Sorry, I do not add tag C# and WPF

Comment: If the columns vary, how will you be able to insert a diff amount of columns?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You have several options: Key-Value Table, Typed XML, Untyped XML

Key-Value: Main problem - all data types stored as string and CAST is your problem (on C# side)

```
CREATE TABLE VarTable (
    ColName varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Value nvarchar(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO VarTable (ColName, Value)
VALUES ('CutomerID','215')
     ,('CustomerName','John')
```

XML

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTable (
    Value XML
)

INSERT INTO XMLTable (Value)
VALUES ('<MyTable><CutomerID>215</CutomerID><CustomerName>John</CustomerName></MyTable>')

SELECT TOP (1) Value FROM XMLTable
```

[MSDN Compare Typed XML to Untyped XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I need some WPF control in C#